# Ansible: silence set_fact

Tags: ansible

`set_fact` seems to output the entire variable value when I run it.

If I try and silence this with `no_log: True` I then get:

`ok: [host] => (item=None)`

How do you completely silence output?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Plugin List](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list). For example [actionable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback/actionable.html) - shows only items that need attention. Next option is [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner) which is able to run in the [background](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html#executing-runner-in-the-background).